# UnsatisfiedLinkError when trying to run an executable jar containing dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jar, uberjar

My Java project has a number of dependencies e.g `Box2d`, `OpenGl` and `OpenAl`
I have the follow list of `plugin`s defined in my `pom.xml`, so using Maven to manage project.
Note: I have dependencies listed at bottom of `pom.xml`, but excluding from here.

I followed this documentation to get started: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source/>
            <target/>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>com.app.game.Main</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

When I run `mvn package`, a `jar` is created i.e `target/test-0.1.jar`
It actually contains all `jar` dependencies and includes native `.so` and `.dll` libraries at root of package.

[image]

But when I try run the application from CLI, I get `UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception.
Am I missing something in `pom`?

```
[rob@work target]$ java -jar test-0.1.jar 
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.app.game.Main).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Catched FileNotFoundException: /home/rob/git/test/target/test-0.1-natives-linux-amd64.jar (No such file or directory), while addNativeJarLibsImpl(classFromJavaJar class com.jogamp.common.os.Platform, classJarURI jar:file:/home/rob/git/test/target/test-0.1.jar!/com/jogamp/common/os/Platform.class, nativeJarBaseName test-0.1-natives-linux-amd64.jar): [ file:/home/rob/git/test/target/test-0.1.jar -> file:/home/rob/git/test/target/ ] + test-0.1-natives-linux-amd64.jar -> slim: jar:file:/home/rob/git/test/target/test-0.1-natives-linux-amd64.jar!/
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/rob/git/test/target/libgluegen-rt.so (/home/rob/git/test/target/liblibgluegen-rt.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1217)
```

Comment: Yes, you're missing a C object code module: /home/rob/git/test/target/libgluegen-rt.so

Comment: why does it expect `libgluegen-rt.so` to be here: `/home/rob/git/test/target/libgluegen-rt.so`. When it's actually at root directory of the `.jar`? i.e `/home/rob/git/test/target/test-0.1.jar/libgluegen-rt.so`

Comment: Because you told the JVM to expect it there.

Comment: Where do I did that? can you provide more info

Comment: I gotta admit that it's well-hidden.  There is a separate path for native modules, but I can't find any info on it.  Haven't had to worry about that for about 8 years now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using following set of `plugins` in `POM.xml` achieved what I was looking for ..

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>  <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>verify</phase>  <!-- bind to the verify phase, to execute after package phase -->
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <programs>
            <program>
                <mainClass>com.app.game.Main</mainClass>
                <id>thegame</id>
            </program>
        </programs>
        <repositoryName>lib</repositoryName>
        <repositoryLayout>flat</repositoryLayout>
        <assembleDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}</assembleDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>prepare-assembly</id>  <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>package</phase>  <!-- bind to the package phase -->
            <goals>
                <goal>assemble</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And `src/assembly/assembly.xml` ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>bin</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>/**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>bin/*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}/bin</directory>
            <lineEnding>keep</lineEnding>
            <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
            <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*</include>
            </includes>
            <fileMode>755</fileMode>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```